# What server settings may cause a flash uploader to return Error#2038

Tags: php, flash, apache, webserver

I have a flash uploader, that has worked fine for years, now all of a sudden it is returning an `Error#2038`.

It actually uploads the first few files fine and then the error kicks in, so I think something has changed on my server to be causing this...

Anyone know what it might be?... kind regards to any responders...

Comment: No it is a file uploader i have built.

Comment: http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=742315

Comment: Have you checked the error/access logs on your web server for any errors?